# How to create a JSON of a List of List of Any in Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, deserialization, json-serialization

The JSON output that I am looking for is

```json
{[[1, 1.5, "String1"], [-2, 2.3, "String2"]]}
```

So I want to have an Array of Arrays and the inner array is storing different types.

How should I store my variables so I can create such JSON in Scala?

I thought of List of Tuples. However, all the available JSON libraries try to convert a Tuple to a map instead of an Array. I am using `json4s` library.

Comment: You will need to use a custom serializer/deserializer for this, but that depends on which JSON library you are using. There are examples of how to write these objects in answers to other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: I am using json4s.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom serializer for those inner arrays using `json4s`:

```
import org.json4s._

class MyTupleSerializer extends CustomSerializer[(Int, Double, String)](format => ({
  case obj: JArray =>
    implicit val formats: Formats = format

    (obj(0).extract[Int], obj(1).extract[Double], obj(2).extract[String])
}, {
  case (i: Int, d: Double, s: String) =>
    JArray(List(JInt(i), JDouble(d), JString(s)))
}))
```

The custom serialiser converts `JArray` into a tuple and back again. This will be used wherever the Scala object being read or written has a value of the appropriate tuple type.

To test this against the sample input I have modified it to make it valid JSON by adding a field name:

```
{"data": [[1, 1.5, "String1"], [-2, 2.3, "String2"]]}
```

I have defined a container class to match this:

```
case class MyTupleData(data: Vector[(Int, Double, String)])
```

The name of the class is not relevant but the field name `data` must match the JSON field name. This uses `Vector` rather than `Array` because `Array` is really a Java type rather than a Scala type. You can use `List` if preferred.

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}

case class MyTupleData(data: Vector[(Int, Double, String)])

object JsonTest extends App {
  val data = """{"data": [[1, 1.5, "String1"], [-2, 2.3, "String2"]]}"""
  implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats + new MyTupleSerializer

  val td: MyTupleData = read[MyTupleData](data)

  println(td) // MyTupleData(Vector((1,1.5,String1), (-2,2.3,String2)))

  println(write(td)) // {"data":[[1,1.5,"String1"],[-2,2.3,"String2"]]}
}
```

If you prefer to use a custom class for the data rather than a tuple, the code looks like this:

```
case class MyClass(i: Int, d: Double, s: String)

class MyClassSerializer extends CustomSerializer[MyClass](format => ({
  case obj: JArray =>
    implicit val formats: Formats = format

    MyClass(obj(0).extract[Int], obj(1).extract[Double], obj(2).extract[String])
}, {
  case MyClass(i, d, s) =>
    JArray(List(JInt(i), JDouble(d), JString(s)))
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List of List rather than List of Tuples.

an easy way to convert list of tuples to list of list is:

```
val listOfList: List[List[Any]] = listOfTuples.map(_.productIterator.toList)
```

I would use jackson, which is a java library and can deal with arbitrary datatypes inside collections of type Any/AnyRef, rather than trying to come up with a custom serializer in one of scala json libraries.

To convert scala List to java List use

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

So, in summary the end list would be:

```
val javaListOfList: java.util.List[java.util.List[Any]] = listOfTuples.map(_.productIterator.toList.asJava).asJava
```

Using this solution, you could have arbitrary length tuples in your list and it would work.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

import collection.JavaConverters._

object TuplesCollectionToJson extends App {

  val tuplesList = List(
    (10, false, 43.6, "Text1"),
    (84, true, 92.1, "Text2", 'X')
  )

  val javaList = tuplesList.map(_.productIterator.toList.asJava).asJava

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(javaList)
  println(json)

}
```

Would produce:

```
[[10,false,43.6,"Text1"],[84,true,92.1,"Text2","X"]]
```

PS: Use this solution only when you absolutely have to work with variable types. If your tuple datatype is fixed, its better to create a json4s specific serializer/deserializer.